# Qual é a origem de "cara" para referir alguém?

Tags: etimologia, origem

Além do significado encontrado na maioria dos dicionários para *cara:*

> cara, s.f: face, rosto.

Qual é a origem de *cara* usada para se referir a alguém?

> Cara, você não vai acreditar!
> Você está em boa forma, cara.

Comment: Pensei que fosse caro na primeira leitura. :) Mas é sujeito. Será que vem de **camarada**?

Comment: Tem "cara" como feminino de "caro", que vem do latim "carus".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Os vários dicionários que consultei incluem essa aceção de *cara* (’indivíduo’) juntamente com *cara* ’rosto’, que vem do grego  *kara*, ou latim *cara*, ou grego via latim (Houaiss, [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/cara), [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/cara/), [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/cara)). Isto sugere implicitamente que *cara* ’indivíduo’ evoluiu de *cara* ’rosto’. Uma possibilidade que me parece plausível é que esse *cara* venha de expressões tipo *cara “(de) qualquer coisa”*, tal como *cara linda, cara estanhada, cara de pau*, etc. Há dois usos destas expressões—como vocativo e para referir um indivíduo—que têm grandes semelhanças com os usos de *cara* ’indíviduo’ e que parecem ser mais antigos. Comparemos os dois usos. Os exemplos que apresento são reais e dos mais antigos que encontrei:

### *Cara* para referir um indivíduo

***Cara* sem mais nada** para referir um indivíduo só encontrei a partir de 1911, e apenas no Brasil  (negrito meu, itálico e restante grafia originais):

> **Esses *caras*** o que pretendem é tambem uma passagem para a Orópa.
> [“Nas zonas”, *O Rio Nu*, Rio de Janeiro, 29 de abril de 1911.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=706736&pesq=esses%20caras&pasta=ano%20191)
>
> — Ó Lupercio, quem é **“aquelle cara”?**
> [“Scena de pugilato”, *Correio Paulistano*, São Paulo, 27 de julho de 1915.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=090972_06&pesq=aquelle%20cara&pasta=ano%20191)

***Cara* de qualquer coisa** para o mesmo efeito é mais antigo e é comum tanto no Brasil como em Portugal:

> Pois acredita **esse cara de vergalho**, que a sua interesseira intimidade com a fera do Areal lhe dá o privilegio exclusivo de insultar […]
> [“Satisfacção ao cavaco do Papeleta”, *O Papeleta*, Rio de Janeiro, 5 de abril de 1843, p. 2.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=846694&pesq=esse%20cara&pasta=ano%20184)
>
> [...] queria só pedir-vos um emprego para **este cara amarella** vosso compatriota.
> [“Partir para ser bispo e acabar sineiro”, *A Epoca*, nº 42, Lisboa, 1849, p. 1.](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=898511&pesq=este%20cara&pasta=ano%20184)
>
> […] os pretos cangueiros paravam para “mirar **o cara-nova**” [um desconhecido recém-chegado].
> [Aluísio Azevedo, *O Mulato*, publicado originalmente em 1881.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=LXxcAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT50&dq=%22O%20cara%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjG-brx27jWAhUK3GMKHUK2CN8Q6AEI8QIwLg#v=onepage&q=%22O%20cara%22&f=false)

O último exemplo é particularmente interessante: “o cara-nova” é o mesmo que *o novo cara*, mas *cara* só por si é ’rosto’ num caso e ’indivíduo’ no outro.

### *Cara* como vocativo

***Cara* sem mais dada** como vocativo só encontrei a partir de 1972 e, novamente, apenas no Brasil:

> — Por que vocês não levam o rapaz doente para um hospital?
> — **Não dá pé, cara**. […] **Sem essa, cara!** Você acha que eu vou deixar […]
> — Mas po que você não vai para casa se tratar?
> — **É cara**, corta essa. […]
> — Onde vocês moram?
> — Não tem lugar certo não, **cara**.
> [“O caminho fácil do vício”, *O Jornal*, Rio de Janeiro, 5-11-1972](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=110523_06&pesq=%22cara%20a%20%C3%BAltima%20vez%22&pasta=ano%20197&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=107441)

Este exemplo de 1976 sugere que este uso era ainda pouco aceite em certos meios:

> […] José Wilker, que já poluiu o ambiente sonoro com a repetição sistemática do termo "cara": **“é sério, cara”; “Até logo, cara”.**
> [*Visão*, vol. 48, n. 1-13, 1976.](https://www.google.pt/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22repeti%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20sistem%C3%A1tica%20do%20termo%20cara%22)

***Cara* de qualquer coisa** como vocativo é comum no Brasil e em Portugal, e já era usado no século XVII:

> —Olhe **sô-*cara* de asno** [“senhor cara de asno”], não leve um *carolo*.
> [D. Francisco Manuel de Mello (1608-66), *Feira dos Anexins*, publicado postumamente em 1875.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=1ZRFAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA7&dq=%22s%C3%B3%20cara%20de%20asno%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJp9m10_DfAhVBmJAKHRHwAeEQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22s%C3%B3%20cara%20de%20asno%22&f=false)
>
> Diga-me, **meu cara de inhame insuado**, porque é que maltrata assim quem nunca lhe fez mal?
> [Tristão de Alencar Araripe Júnior, *Luzinha: romance de costumes cearences*, Rio de Janeiro, 1878.](https://archive.org/stream/Luizinha#page/n81/mode/2up/search/meu+cara+de+inhame)
>
> Atreve-te **meu cara de demonio**, que já tens mesmo cara de condemnado!
> [Bento Moreno, *Comedia do campo: scenas do Minho*, Lisboa, 1877.](https://archive.org/stream/comediadocampos00moregoog#page/n113/mode/2up/search/%22cara+de%22)

Uma diferença entre os usos de *cara* “sem mais nada” e *cara* “de qualquer coisa” é que este último é quase sempre provocador ou insultuoso. Mas é comum amigos usarem termos provocativos para se dirigirem uns aos outros, além de que caindo o “de qualquer coisa” o insulto também desaparece. E segundo o [Michalis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/cara/) e o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/cara) o uso de *cara* “sem mais nada” também pode ser provocador ou impolido.

Comment: Excelente resposta; na terra da minha mãe é comum dizer-se "não conheço tal cara", para se referir que não se conhece a pessoa em causa.

Comment: @João, é imediatamente compreensível, e creio aliás que já ouvi coisas desse tipo.  Onde é a terra da tua mãe?

Comment: fica na zona de Alcobaça; aliás temos a velha expressão "essa cara não me é estranha", entre tantas outras que citaste. A tua justificação parece-me muito mais coerente que aquela que refere que a expressão vem do gaélico.

Comment: João, Não estou a ver a palavra vir diretamente da Irlanda ou Escócia. Mas nós temos algumas palavras que se pensam vir das línguas celtiberas anteriores a colonização romana. Mas como o autor da resposta diz, teria de estar atestado mais cedo no Brasil e em Portugal. Eu procurei por todo o lado e não encontrei nada.

Answer (score 4):

Pode ainda ter origem celta: *cara*, em irlandês, e *caraid*, em gaélico, significam ’amigo’. Logo, ao dizer: "Nossa, cara, que coisa", você estaria dizendo "Nossa, amigo, que coisa".

Em Portugal, contudo, essa gíria não existe. Poderia ser um arcaísmo brasileiro, tendo desaparecido em Portugal. Mas então esse uso teria que ser atestado antes da década de 60 no Brasil e em tempos pretéritos, em Portugal.

Answer (score 2):

Segundo a [Revista Decifra-me (2011)](https://revistadeciframe.com/2011/10/18/girias/), tem origem na década de 60 durante a jovem guarda (negrito meu):

> GÍRIAS: NA BOCA DOS JOVENS E ADULTOS
>
> [...]
>
> ANOS 60
>
> aldeia global (nosso mundo), bacana (bom, bonito), boa pinta (de boa
> aparência), boazuda (mulher bonita), bolinha (estimulante), cafona
> (feio), calhambeque (carro velho), **cara (indivíduo)**, carango
> (carro), certinha (mulher bonita), chapa (amigo), dar tábua
> (recusar-se a dançar), duca (ótimo), é fogo! (é difícil), é uma brasa,
> mora! (é espevitada, danada esticada (passar por vários restaurantes e
> bares noturnos),fossa (depressão, crise existencial),gamar (namorar),
> gata (mulher bonita), grana (dinheiro), jovem guarda (movimento
> artístico musical), legal! (ótimo!),mancar (desrespeitar compromisso),
> minissaia (saia curta), paca (muito), pão (homem bonito), papo firme
> (conversa séria), papo furado (conversa boba), pé de chinelo (pessoa
> sem expressão), pelego (líder sindical governista), pode vir quente
> que estou fervendo (excitada), pra frente (moderno), quadrado
> (conservador), sifo (deu-se mal), sifu (deu-se mal), tremendão (rapaz
> bonito), uma brasa, mora (bom, ótimo!), ziriguidum (samba no pé,
> molejo de mulata).

Comment: Já aqui, creio que a Revista Deciframe não fez um bom trabalho. Encontrei *cara* com o sentido de 'pessoa' num livro de 1927: ["Quem é aquele cara?"](https://books.google.pt/books?id=2MXLDgAAQBAJ&pg=PT33&dq=%22passar+Quem+%C3%A9+aquele+cara%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjHu7_Lwb7WAhXMpZQKHevCD8kQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22passar%20Quem%20%C3%A9%20aquele%20cara%22&f=false); +1 na mesma.

Comment: Talvez o uso apareceu naquela época mas isso não explica a origem....

Comment: @Peixoto, a revista diz *cara* 'indivíduo' ("quem é aquele cara?"), mas provavelmente queria referir-se ao vocativo ("oi cara, tudo bem?") Nas minhas pesquisas encontrei a primeira logo por volta de 1910, mas a segunda bem mais tarde.

Answer (score 1):

A palavra χαρακτήρ (transliterado: kharactér ou charactér) tem tudo a ver com "cara" se considerarmos seu significado original no Grego. Dentre os significados encontram-se: marca; representação; face; fisionomia; personagem; papel; indivíduo; semelhante; pessoa mencionada anteriormente. A palavra χαράσσω (kharássõ ou charásso)), diretamente atrelada a χαρακτήρ significa imprimir ou carimbar. Em sentido metafórico pode incluir uma pessoa marcante ou um líder.

Em todos estes significados a palavra "cara" se enquadra:

- Olhe a cara dele.
- Quem é esse cara?
- Teu filho é a tua cara!
- É esse o cara que apareceu ontem.
- Com certeza, você é o cara!
- Cara ou coroa?

A redução de uma palavra é comum na evolução diacrônica das palavras e geralmente emerge na linguagem coloquial. Parece-me que se trata de uma especialização seguida de metaplasmos de supressão e perda (apócope), em que χαρακτήρ assumiu, do Grego até o Português, formas distintas para ressaltar significados distintos. Origem mais provável para a palavra "cara", seja na dinâmica da linguagem, seja no conteúdo semântico.

Já de muito tempo moedas são cunhadas (χαράσσω) com a [fisionomia de autoridades contendo a inscrição do nome](https://www.bibliaon.com/versiculo/mateus_22_17-21). Creio ser essa a associação mais antiga. Segue uma moeda de prata contendo a imagem de [image: Cesar Ditator Perpétuo].

No Brasil uma revista focada em [pessoas ricas e famosas](https://www.portalimprensa.com.br/noticias/ultimas_noticias/3502/a+historia+da+revista+caras) de nome "Caras" ganhou força em 1993, a cara da classe alta da sociedade. Por outro lado, até na astronomia, a segunda [estrela mais brilhante](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_Canum_Venaticorum) da constelação Canes Venatici recebeu o nome "Chara", termo oriundo de Χαρά (transliterado: khará ou chará), que significa alegria, brilho, graça e αστέρας (transliterado: astéras), que significa astro ou celebridade. Em sentido abstrato, os aspectos semânticos são os mesmos.

Os termo "cara" é muito usado no Brasil, assim como "chará", que se refere a uma outra pessoa com o mesmo nome, semelhante, ou ainda alguém com quem se tenha uma forte relação confiança ou empatia.
Quanto à passagem do Grego para o Português, a menos do alfabeto, a palavra nem sempre precisa passar pelo Latim. Muitas delas são simples transliterações, geralmente a partir do Grego Koiné ou Ático.

Obs.: A transliteração dupla refere-se ao Grego Koiné seguido do Grego Moderno.

Referências:

Comment: Fiz uns ajustes para ficar mais claro. A revista caras tornou-se famosa em 1993. Não entendi o 1911. O registro a que me refiro é de outro site que cita escrito do século XIX. O rastreio da passagem pode ser da forma complicada ou simples. O próprio Latim teve muitos dialectos e diferenças no uso dos próprios caracteres. A forma mais simples é partir do Grego e transliterar, o que, se funcionar, posso considerar a passagem direta. Caso a palavra seja própria do Latim, parto deste para o Português.

Comment: Melo, ok, a revista [Caras argentina (a primeira) foi lançada em 1992; a brasileira foi em 1993](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caras). 1911 é ano do exemplo mais antigo que eu encontrei em que "cara" significa ’pessoa’ (vê na minha resposta). O tal registo do século XIX não é de “caras”; é da palavra americana “dude”. O artigo que tu linkaste é que traduz “dude” por “cara” (nalguns sítios; noutros deixa mesmo "dude") . Repara que o artigo não diz nada sobre o Brasil; fala é de Nova Iorque. O artigo é possivelmente tradução automática: aquilo tá tão macarrónico.

Comment: Mello, cá está: [este post que referenciaste sobre a "origem da palavra 'Cara'"](https://imwechsel.com/pt/qual-e-a-origem-da-palavra-cara/) é uma tradução [deste *Where did the word "dude" come from?"](https://theweek.com/articles/457871/where-did-word-dude-come-from) Aquilo não tem nada que ver com a palavra "cara".

Comment: Ok Jacinto. Apesar de ser curioso o referido post, eu o removi de minha resposta e incluí a moeda, que é o mais relevante. Inclusive para a brincadeira de "cara" ou "coroa". Relação mais antiga do termo associado ao significado de imprimir ou cunhar a imagem de um rosto.

Comment: Nenhuma das fontes que consultei confirmam os sentidos "personagem; papel; indivíduo; semelhante; pessoa mencionada anteriormente" que tu atribuis ao grego antigo *charakter*; e "face", só no caso de moedas ([CNRTL](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/caract%C3%A8re); o Houaiss diz o mesmo). Qual é a tua fonte? Tu sugeres que *cara* no sentido "rosto" vem também de *charakter*; mas de acordo com todos os dicionários que vi, vem do grego *kara*, "cabeça" (alguns acrescentam "face"), via latim.  Quando vais contra os dicionários, deverias apresentar alguma justificação, não?

Answer (score -1):

Provavelmente da palavra indígena “*cara*” [com acento na pronúncia no segundo a - car(á)], a qual significa senhor.

As variantes são:

> Senhora: Cunhatã
>
> Senhorita: Cunhataí
>
> Senhorito: Caraí

Comment: Achei interessante. Fontes? Reforçará sua resposta.

Comment: @gustavo-roriz indígena é bem abrangente, tens referência a algum dialeto específico?

Answer (score -2):

Vem do tupi "Caraíba", homem branco, extrangeiro.

Comment: Diego, como é que sabes que é isso?

Comment: Poderias, por favor, adicionar alguma referência, como algum trecho de livro ou dicionário que sustena esta afirmação?